# Is there any way to set up the Telegram bot on LAN?

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

I am very new to writing bots and relatively new to programming in general. I need to write a simple Telegram bot to compliment an event with weak mobile network. There will be a local wi-fi network without the access to internet though.

So, straight to the question: is there a way to host a server in the LAN network to serve the Telegram bot on it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write/run a telegram bot in telegram itself.

You can't run the standard telegram in lan without the telegram server's.

[Is it possible to host telegram on my own server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34617157/is-it-possible-to-host-telegram-on-my-own-server)

> So as long as the server itself is not open-source the entire Telegram eco-system cannot be considered open-source, even though there is an open API and official open-source clients.

> There seem to be some unofficial telegram servers, but it's not clear how compatible they are with existing clients.

**Check this for bots:**

[Bots: An introduction for developers](https://core.telegram.org/bots)

And you can only use specially encrypted telegram chats with the standard app for tablets, smartphones, etc..

For example, I use an unofficial Telegram on a debian but I can't see the encrypted chats I created with the official app on my smartphone.

[Using a Local Bot API Server](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#using-a-local-bot-api-server)

> Using a Local Bot API Server
> The Bot API server source code is available at telegram-bot-api. You can run it locally and send the requests to your own server instead of https://api.telegram.org.

[telegram-bot-api](https://github.com/tdlib/telegram-bot-api)